# How to quickly expand brackets raised to a power such as: $(a_0+...+a_n)^m$

Tags: power-series, perturbation-theory

I'm following a course on singular perturbation problems and finding the expansion of the solutions of equations depending on a parameter. In those problems I often have to expand brackets raised to powers and I wanted to know if there were any tricks to do it fast?

Example:

$$(x_0 + cx_1+c^2x_2 + O(c^3))^3$$

So here technically, I'm only concerned by writing down terms that are not $O(c^3)$.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Generating_function

Comment: @Gary thank you very much!